# BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER is evaluating to empty string in a Windows self hosted pipeline runner

Tags: yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

Below is my YML file. When the pipeline is run on a fork's changes, the BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER is coming as empty string.

Wondering what the trick is to get it right.

```
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  branches:
    feature/*:
      - step:
          name: 'Build and Test'
          runs-on:
          - 'self.hosted'
          - 'windows'
          - 'aio'
          script:
            - echo "Build and test"
            - ant -buildfile ReportGen/build.xml jar
            - echo "Deploying artifacts to /denver/integration/${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}/"
            - jf rt u out/dist/* "test-generic-local/denver/integration/${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}/"
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the {}?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "when the pipeline is run on a fork's changes" part? I think this could be the root of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured what was going on. The pipeline runner is self hosted running on Windows. BitBucket pipelines use Powershell as the shell interpreting those script blocks. BitBucket should do a better job explaining this nugget instead of using script examples that use Bash like scripts.
Once I used $Env:BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER to refer to vars coming from system environment, everything worked as expected.

Comment: Didn't even know Windows runners were a thing!