# Bitbucket Pipeline custom variable is not showing its value in step script

Tags: selenium, maven, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

- I have created a pipeline for running automation script from bitbucket, when I trigger build with docker container all custom variable is working (it pass the correct values) but when I run the same project in self.hosted machine and pass the variables it show blank values.

Below is the sample of pipeline file

```html
# This is an example Starter pipeline configuration
# Use a skeleton to build, test and deploy using manual and parallel steps
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: atlassian/default-image:2
pipelines:
  pull-requests:                #Trigger pipeline project on each Pull-Request
    '**':
      - step:
          name: 'version check'
          image: maven:3.3.9
          caches:
            - maven
          script:
            - echo "Your versions here..."
            - mvn --version
      - step:
          name: 'Clean and Build'
          script:
            - mvn -f TestAutomation/pom.xml clean compile
  custom:
    Automation-Run:                 #Name of this pipeline
      - variables:
          - name: testngFile
            default: "src/test/resources/testng"
          - name: browser
            default: "CHROME"
            allowed-values:           # optionally restrict variable values
              - "CHROME"
              - "FIREFOX"
          - name: environment
            default: STAGING
            allowed-values:
              - "STAGING"
              - "QA"
              - "PROD"
          - name: forkCount
            default: "0"
          - name: tags
            default: Regression
      - step:
          name: 'Connect to Runner & Automation-Run'
          runs-on:
            - self.hosted
            - windows
            - testautomation
          script:
            - cd TestAutomation
            - .\Example1.bat ${testngFile} ${browser} ${environment} ${tags}
          artifacts:
            - /target/surefire-reports/**.xml
```

inside Example1.bat file I have mentioned below command
mvn clean test -Dproject.testngFile=%1 -Dbrowser.name=%2 -Dproject.environment=%3 -Dcucumber.filter.tags=@%4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGjiX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0hQh.png)

I am expecting when user enter any values, it picked and stored into variable and those variables are pass to Example1.bat as runtime command line args.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/q/72776912/11715259 answer your question?

Comment: 1. Given post is provide the way of solution
https://stackoverflow.com/q/72776912/11715259

Comment: Yes, @N1ngu the given post is helpful for me. it's working with the given approach. Thanks :)